# How to circumvent siege concurrency socket select timed out

Tags: socket, benchmark, load-testing, concurrency

Being trying to test load capacity of a web site. I am using an aws ubuntu xenial server t2.micro as test client and have SIEGE 3.0.8 and apache benchmark  Version 2.3

while `ab -c 100 -n 100000 url` completes without an issue thes on the other hand `siege -c 100 -i -b -f urldatabase.txt -t 20m` produces

```
** SIEGE 3.0.8
** Preparing 150 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...[alert] socket: 470009600 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: 562329344 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: -159443200 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: -83908864 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: 109123328 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: 654649088 select timed out: Connection timed out
```

Is there any tweaking that is necessary ? I have followed a tutorial on [easyengine.com](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/sysctl-conf/) but it didn't help still having the same issue

Comment: I've only been using siege for a few days at this point. I've run into the same problem. So far, I've just been throttling down the number of concurrent users until I don't consistently receive this error.

Comment: @josh Isn't the whole point of siege to figure out how to make your server handle MORE connections? Lowering the connections isn't going to help you improve your server

Answer (score 1):

Please update the siege.

```
wget http://download.joedog.org/siege/siege-4.0.4.tar.gz
tar -zxf siege-4.0.4.tar.gz
cd siege-4.0.4
./configure
make 
sudo make install
siege.config
```

You may need to issue the following command:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/siege /usr/bin/
```